# mySQL - Selecting all records where all columns are unique

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a table like this

```
id  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6
1    1     2     3     4     5     6
2    2     1     4     3     6     5
3    1     1     2     3     4     5
```

I would want to select the rows where every field has a different value. The out put would be

```
id  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6
1    1     2     3     4     5     6
2    2     1     4     3     6     5
```

I know you can do this

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE col1 <> col2 AND col2 <> col3...
```

but that would take forever with this many columns. Is there a specific function for determining if all columns are unique?

Comment: `FIELD()` will limit the amount of comparisons to the number of columns

Comment: It might help to know what the data set is? For instance if this was the actual data set you could check for `SUM(cols) != 15`....Also, can this be avoided on `INSERT`?

Comment: Did you try group concate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can unpivot your table using `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT id
FROM (
  SELECT id, col1 AS col
  FROM mytable

  UNION ALL

  SELECT id, col2
  FROM mytable

  UNION ALL

  SELECT id, col3
  FROM mytable

  UNION ALL

  SELECT id, col4
  FROM mytable

  UNION ALL

  SELECT id, col5
  FROM mytable

  UNION ALL

  SELECT id, col6
  FROM mytable) AS t
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT col) = 6
```

If you want all columns selected then you do something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable 
WHERE id IN ( .... above query here ...)
```

Unfortunately MySQL does not have an `UNPIVOT` operator that would make the above query less verbose.

Answer (score 2):

A little less verbose than your solution, although it doesn't scale perfectly if the number of columns is excessively large:

```
SELECT
    *    -- In actual live code you would of course never use '*'
FROM
    MyTable
WHERE
    col1 NOT IN (col2, col3, col4, col5, col6) AND
    col2 NOT IN (col3, col4, col5, col6) AND
    col3 NOT IN (col4, col5, col6) AND
    col4 NOT IN (col5, col6) AND
    col5 NOT IN (col6)    -- Done as an IN just to be consistent
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this i hope this will helping you

```
select 
(SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT col1) FROM table) as col1,
(SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT col2) FROM table) as col2,
(SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT col3) FROM table) as col3,
(SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT col4) FROM table) as col4
```